# How do I use received JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, post

I'm reading an integration API and it says it will send requests in this format:

```
content-type: application/json
accept: application/json
x-gsc-api-key: lRDs8NfsVTmHD8SC1234

{ 
  "name"      : "testuser",
  "password"  : "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6",
  "reference" : "b86de61-af20-4c47-af9a-6f2edeebc4fe" 
}
```

I want to server the requests with PHP. I know some other posts also ask something along the same lines, but they were sending the request via AJAX method. I don't know which method the request is going to be sent.

Can I just reference the variables $_POST['name'] and $_POST['password'] to get the values? Or do I need to call json_decode($_POST)?

Is this information enough the write a PHP script that server the request?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use `$_POST` directly. You will have to manually extract the response body, `json_decode` it and work on the results. But it's easy to do:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

echo $data->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the json_decode() function for this (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i read the question correctly but >.>

```
$json = '{"name":"testuser","password":"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6","reference":"b86de61-af20-4c47-af9a-6f2edeebc4fe"}';
$data = @json_decode($json);

$name = $data->name;
$password = $data->password;
$ref = $data->reference;
   echo "${name} ${password} ${ref}";
```

or use the true like below. . .

```
$json = '{"name":"testuser","password":"098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6","reference":"b86de61-af20-4c47-af9a-6f2edeebc4fe"}';

$data = @json_decode($json, true);


$name = $data['name'];
$password = $data['password'];
$ref = $data['reference'];
   echo "${name} ${password} ${ref}";
```

Answer (score 0):

No - you can't - however you can convert the JSON to `$_POST` like so:

```
<?php
    $_POST = array_merge($_POST, json_decode(file_get_contents("php://stdin"), true));
?>
```